# Why is this returning the wrong answer?

Tags: arduino-uno

Why does this print output -3? xpos can be any value.

```
void loop() {
xPos = analogRead(xPin);
yPos = analogRead(yPin);
pwm = xPos*(255/1023);
Serial.println(pwm);

}
```

Comment: What types are your variables declared as? (`int`, `float`, etc)

Comment: xPos and yPos are ints and pwm is currently float i tried int aswell, and its outputting 0 not -3 sorry, (xPos*255)/1023 outputs -3.

Comment: @user10936 Could you edit your question to include the `setup()` loop and the declarations of `xPos`, `yPos`, and `pwm`. There could be something there that you're overlooking.

Comment: Just swap the priority of the operations. So use `pwm = xPos*255/1023;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `(255/1023)` is being treated as an integer calculation, meaning the result gets truncated to 0. You can make the compiler promote it to a floating-point calculation by explicitly making at least one of the values floating-point. For example:

```
pwm = xPos*(255.0f/1023.0f);
```

Comment: Is the `f` designator necessary? Without it does the compiler treat the calculation as `double`s and then re-cast it to `float` or something? Also, is it not sufficient to add the decimal point to just the numerator or denominator? I know it *works* in 'regular C++ on a computer', but in an embedded environment would it bloat the program memory?

Comment: @chaaarlie2 Without the `f` designator, a C++ compiler would treat it as `double` during the calculation, which normally requires slightly more resources. Most Arduinos treat `float` and `double` the same though so it wouldn't necessarily make a practical difference. It's not usually a good idea to rely on platform quirks like that though.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 I would always put the `f` designator on both values, simply for consistency. The chances are that the compiler would be smart enough to convert the integer to floating-point at compile-time (rather than run-time), so it probably doesn't matter from a technical point-of-view.

Comment: I prefer the format pwm = xPos *  val1 / (float) val2; which works equally for hardcoded values, constants and variables.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer correctly suggested writing

```
pwm = xPos*(255.0f/1023.0f);
```

in place of the original form `pwm = xPos*(255/1023);`.  But because 255/1023 - 1/4 = -1/1364 which is fairly small (ie it differs by 1 part in 1364), just saying

```
pwm = xPos/4;
```

will usually give the correct result or nearly so.

Note, the following python program shows that this result is exact 514 times as xPos ranges from 0 to 1023, and is one too large 510 times, which for many processes being controlled by PWM signals is close enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
c = [0]*8
for i in range(1024):
    vf = int(i*255.0/1023.0)
    vi = i/4
    d = vi-vf
    c[d+3] += 1
    #print '{:5} {:5} {:5} {:5}'.format(i, d, vi, vf)
print c
```